# Cypress cy.request expect to throw/fail

Tags: javascript, cypress, chai

Is there any way to write a test case to expect `cy.request` to fail(non-2** response) on certain params?

I attempted to use the following snippet:

```js
it('intentionally fails', () => {
  expect(
    () => {
      cy.request({
        method: 'POST',
        url: `https://valid.url/api/items`,
        body: {name: "foo"},
      })
    }
  ).to.throw('bar')
})
```

but it fails with:

```
AssertionError
expected [Function] to throw an error
```

This is API-only project, so basically I only use `cy.request` everywhere.

Without the `expect` function block it fails with:

```
CypressError
cy.request() failed on

The response we received from your web server was:

  > 500: Internal Server Error
```

Comment: Are you using Cypress 6? The intercept command might be useful for you. https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/intercept.html#Comparison-to-cy-route

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To check if the status of the response is not 200, add the `failOnStatusCode: false` option.

Cypress catches internal errors and does not re-throw them so `expect(...).to.throw` is not going to see anything.

```js
cy.request({
  method: 'POST',
  // url: `https://valid.url/api/items`,
  url: 'http://example.com/api/items',
  body: {name: "foo"},
  failOnStatusCode: false
})
.then(response => {
  expect(response.status).to.be.gt(299)  // status returned is 404
})
```

The `500: Internal Server Error` is specific to your API, but `cy.request` is doing it's job as by default it is configured to fail the test when the request fails.